# divide batch in python tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've tried to set a batch size and run the Autoencoder program because there is not enough memory for using full batch. So I tried to use the `tf.train.batch`. but since the argument of the function is a tensor, I tried to convert the np array to a tensor with `tf.convert_to_tensor`. But the memory exceeded 2GB and could not be changed into a tensor. How can I train with mini batches?
below is my code.

```
N_img=47000000
batch_size=100
X_train = np.zeros(shape=(N_img, Freq_LEN, LOOK_LEN, 1), dtype='float32')
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FRM_LEN/2,FRM_LEN/2,1])  #FRM_LEN=256
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FRM_LEN/2,FRM_LEN/2,1])
X_train=tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train)
X_train_batch= tf.train.batch(X_train,batch_size=batch_size)

print("Start training..")

for step in range(n_iters):
    sess.run(optm, feed_dict={x: X_train_batch, y: X_train_batch, keepprob: 0.7})
    if step % 100 == 0:
       print(step,sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: X_train_batch, y: X_train_batch, keepprob: 1}))

print("finish training")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create a custom `generate_batch` function that doesn't require a tensor argument (to avoid tf.convert_to_tensor operation), example:

```
import numpy as np
batch_size = 100

X_train = np.zeros(shape=(N_img, Freq_LEN, LOOK_LEN, 1), dtype='float32')
y_train = np.zeros(shape=(N_img, Freq_LEN, LOOK_LEN, 1), dtype='float32')

data_index = 0

def generate_batch(batch_size):
    global data_index
    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, Freq_LEN, LOOK_LEN, 1), dtype=np.float32)  #the same shapes as train data
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, Freq_LEN, LOOK_LEN, 1), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(batch_size):
        batch[i] = X_train[data_index]
        labels[i] = y_train[data_index]
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(X_train)
    return batch, labels

for step in range(n_iters):
    X_train_batch, X_train_batch = generate_batch(batch_size)
    sess.run(optm, feed_dict={x: X_train_batch, y: X_train_batch, keepprob: 0.7})
    if step % 100 == 0:
        print(step,sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: X_train_batch, y: X_train_batch, keepprob: 1}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Force your batch handling to happen on the CPU:

```
....
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FRM_LEN/2,FRM_LEN/2,1])  #FRM_LEN=256
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FRM_LEN/2,FRM_LEN/2,1])
    X_train=tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train)
    X_train_batch= tf.train.batch(X_train,batch_size=batch_size)
print("Start training..")
....
```